# Criteria for measure convergence implying convergence a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose the function $g_n = \sup_{m \geq n} |f_n-f_m|\to 0$ in measure. Show $f_n \to f$ a.e.

Suppose instead that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m\{ |f_n - f|>\epsilon\} < \infty$. Show $f_n \to f$ a.e.  Here $m$ denotes our measure.

I am not sure which technique I am to apply on these types of problems.

I know that convergence in measure gives a subsequence convergent a.e., and that we can usually write an intersection of unions of certain sets to get a set of measure 0 where we DON'T converge, giving us the result. But what are those sets here, and how do I even apply that technique to the first problem in particular?

Comment: What do you mean by a supremum of a sequence of sets? I guess it should read $$g_n := \sup_{m \geq n} |f_n-f_m|$$ instead, right?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let $\omega \in \Omega$ and suppose that $(f_n(\omega))_n$ does not converge. Then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ \omega \in A_m := \left\{ \sup_{n \geq m} |f_n-f_m|>\varepsilon \right\}$$ for all $m \geq n$. Consequently, $$\omega \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{m \geq n} A_m = \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n.$$ By Fatou's lemma (or, alternatively, the continuty of the measure), $$m \left( \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \right) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} m(A_n) = 0.$$ This shows that $(f_n)_n$ converges almost everywhere.
2. Hint: Apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma.